# How to make a page redirect upon refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect, refresh

1. From a HTML page, is there a way to auto redirect to the home page since the javascript don't run when i refresh the page?
2. how do i add in a 3 seconds interval before redirecting it to another page? (at the end of my quiz)

   ```
   seconds = seconds -1;
   if (seconds <= 0) {
   window.location.href="#select";
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the onLoad attribute to specify a new location, something like:

```
<body onLoad="myRedirectFunction()">
...
...
</body>
<script>
myRedirectFunction()
{
window.location.assign("http://myRedirectLocation.com/blahblah");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this script to automatically re-direct to another URL upon page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com"
</script>
```